# jquery selectbox - how to make it disappear on mouse out?

Tags: jquery, plugins, mouseout

I am using the [jquery selectbox plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuerySelectBox), and my problem is that I want to make the drop down list disappear when I move the mouse outside the selectable area.

do you have any idea if this is possible?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On line 148 of the select box code there is this:

```
                .bind('blur.selectBox', function() {
                    if( !control.hasClass('selectBox-active') ) return;
                    control.removeClass('selectBox-active');
                    select.trigger('blur');
                });
```

You have to add on a `mouseout`